# I disagreed to IOS 15 ToS, Apple has blocked all access to my phone until I agree. Can I “agree under duress”?

Tags: terms-of-service

I inadvertently updated my new iPhone to IOS 15 (store personnel had set up auto-update w/out asking, update occurred when my wireless charger failed so I used a wired charging device).  I do not use the Cloud, Apple says if I want my phone numbers, photos and texts, I need to agree to ToS.  It will not uninstall update, or assist me to retrieve my info any other way -- says I can wright my own program to override it (as if!)

Comment: maybe smartphones are not for you if you consider this an issue

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you don't use the cloud, they don't hold any of your data you might want to recover, do they? Or are you unable to operate your phone without connection to the cloud?

Comment: You already agreed to an earlier version of the license when you bought the phone. Is there a specific change you are objecting to?

Comment: "Duress" in law usually means a threat of immediate physical harm, like a literal gun to your head, not a figurative one.  Losing your data (which they will say you should have backed up anyway) doesn't count.